# C# Wrong Path even with @

Tags: c#, path, uwp, escaping, directory

Actually, I just want to count the data in a folder.
Unfortunately, the path is not recognized correctly.

```
            string tets = @"C:\Users\Tom\Downloads\AppBilder";
            [...]
            StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            [...]
            Ordnerquelle = folder.Path;


int directoryCount = Directory.GetDirectories(tets, " * ", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(tets, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
count = directoryCount + fileCount;
```

The debugger displays the following:

- tets:          "C:\\Users\\Tom\\Downloads\\AppBilder"
- Ordnerquelle   "C:\\Users\\Tom\\Downloads\\AppBilder"
- count: 0

The folder is not empty!
What am I missing ?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3xhG.jpg)

Comment: Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx you only need to pass one parameter this method.

Comment: Hm, fileCount should be OK, but GetDirectories should probably have "*" for a searchPattern, instead of " * ".

Comment: The debugger will display the escaped value with double-backslash. If you click on the magnifying glass icon, you will see that the actual values contain only a single backslash per path delimiter.

Comment: Have you actually run `count = directoryCount + fileCount`? When the debugger program indicator is pointing to a line of code, that means the debugger has not run that line yet.

Comment: `" * "` means "where it starts with a space, has 0-many characters, then ends with a space. So unless you have directories that match this criteria, none will be returned.

Comment: Are you sure you're developing UWP app? The UWP doesn't not allow to use path to get files or folders or other things.

Comment: @yaakoc Thanks for the clarification. So the Path is ok. But the counter   stays at zero, even with the modified search pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guss my problem was that UWP  can only access files and folders if
the user manually selected with the FileOpenPicker or FolderPicker.

In my example the folowing lines are executed:

```
StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
string tets = folder.Path;
```

after that Iam calling a Methode wich look something like that:

```
public static int docount();
{
int directoryCount = Directory.GetDirectories(tets, " * ", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(tets, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
count = directoryCount + fileCount;
}
```

***!!Even if the user has chosen the path, it is passed as a string.!!***

**My Solution:**

```
StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
int count = await Manager.docount(quelle);
```

and

```
public class Manager
{
public static async Task<int> ErstellltbilderlisteAsync(StorageFolder quelle)
        {
            int idcounter = 0;

            var query = quelle.CreateFileQuery();
            var fileList = await query.GetFilesAsync();
            foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
            {
                idcounter++;

            }
            return idcounter;
}
}
```

I don't know if that's the easiest way, but I'm still learning.
Thanks @Bite who got me on the right path.

Comment: You're welcome. You're on the right direction. But, you could return ` fileList.Count;` directly instead of using `foreach` loop.

Comment: If you have solved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is small issue in your code. You should not provide a space in the search pattern. You used `" * "` instead of `"*"`.

The modified code as below:

```
int directoryCount = Directory.GetDirectories(tets, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;

int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(tets, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```

Comment: I modifyed the search Pattern. But still the counter stays at zero.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in the searchPattern option in GetDirectories call.

[image]

Code after removing the extra spaces in search string:

```
int directoryCount = Directory.GetDirectories(tets, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answear. But my counter still stays at Zero =(